# Should I use workflow in my module development?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

Should I use workflow in my module development? I feel like it complicates things and make the development itself prone to errors. Does the benefit really outweigh the hassle I need to go through to implement workflow? Instead of just using actions and buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as I know, workflows are going to disappear in following versions of Odoo, instead of them there are going to be only buttons calling methods which will modify the status of the object.

I have just modified a workflow in a custom module. This module was made to work only in version 8, and I have overwritten the workflow. If I wanted the module to be moved to version 9 and more, may be I would have used only buttons and methods as you have written.

I guess you can do it in both ways, depending on whether you are in a hurry or not.